# exec aapt on Linux by java

Tags: java, android, linux, runtime.exec, aapt

I'm finding a way to use Runtime.exec() in Linux. I have an aapt Linux version and trying to get information of apk file with aapt. I tried:

```
rt.exec(new String[] {"bash", "-c","." + new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "dist/lib/aapt d badging \"" + files + "\""});
```

but it seems wrong. It doesn't return result.
Normal command in Terminal that worked:

```
$ ./home/codeblue/NetbeansProjects/APKTools/dist/lib/aapt d badging "Zing Mp3.apk"
```

Anyone please helps :(

Comment: Could you provide me the normal command you would use on the terminal?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I added the command that works on Terminal

Comment: Did you simply try this : `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", " ./home/codeblue/NetbeansProjects/APKTools/dist/lib/aapt d badging Zing Mp3.apk"});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh i found out that using absolute path isn't working. With "-c" i use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", " ./lib/aapt d badging ZingMp3.apk"});
```

This's working fine. Thanks for helping me.